# When does this function equal 'true'?

Tags: piecewise

I've used Mathematica to find the function $f(t)$ and I found this:

[image]

> Q: What does 'true' say about the function. Is it always equal to $ae^{-\frac{t}{p}}$ or what does it mean?

Comment: [Piecewise >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html) : _The $cond_i$ are evaluated in turn, until one of them is found to yield True._   Also,  _the $val_i$ corresponding to the first $cond_i$ that yields True is returned as the value of the piecewise function._

Answer (score 2):

As kglr explained in his comment, the conditions are evaluated in order, so True there means Not (`!`) any of the prior conditions. It is like an Else at the end of an If statement.

To see this specific case, we can use `FullSimplify` and `Reduce` to find what `t` values are left:

```
FullSimplify[!{t == T || t > T || t == T/2 || (2 t >= T && t < T)}]
Reduce[%, t]
```

This returns:  `t < T && 2 t < T` and then `(T <= 0 && t < T) || (T > 0 && t < T/2)`.

So the final answer is `f[t]= a E^(-(t/p))` when  either `t<T/2` (if `T>0`) or `t<T` (`if T<=0`).

Comment: Wouldn't call `If[]` a loop myself; also a closer analogy would be the `cases` statements in some languages, where the case corresponding to `True` is the "default case".

Comment: Thanks @J.M. +1. I should have been more precise. I was speaking colloquially with loop. I already said else statement so was trying to avoid saying if statement too. I edited to correct. I am used to if, elseif, else where else is the catch all at the end.